# Imprecise moving on an angle

Tags: javascript, math, p5.js

When I move an object along an angle, it doesn't move precisely along that angle. My mouse wouldn't show up in the screenshot, so my mouse is approximately on the green point.

[image]

I'm using the p5.js library.

This is the code that matters:

```
this.pos.x += cos(this.r) * this.speed;
this.pos.y += sin(this.r) * this.speed;
this.r = Math.atan2(mouseY - getPos(player.x, player.y).y, mouseX - getPos(player.x, player.y).x);
```

And this is the getPos function:

```
function getPos(x, y) {
  return createVector(x / 256 * width, y / 256 * height);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move the object in direction of the mouse, do not go over the insecure angle determination, just normalize the difference vector

```
dx = mouseX - this.pos.x;
dy = mouseY - this.pos.y;
ds = Math.hypot(dx,dy);
this.pos.x += dx/ds * this.speed;
this.pos.y += dy/ds * this.speed;
```

You might want to think about which geometry to use, the screen geometry or the geometry of the model. As the scaling is not isotropic, `width` and `height` can be different, the angles in these geometries will differ. Also, you should not compute the difference of screen and model variables, it seems that the coordinates of the `player` object are model geometry, while `mouseX, mouseY` is screen geometry. It seems to me that you compute the update in the screen geometry, but add it to the model geometry coordinates.

It would be better to have all computations in model geometry and translate to screen geometry only while painting the scene and converse in the mouse event handler.

Comment: I have no idea what anything you said means, but your code does work!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use x, y values multiplied by width, height?

Does mouse or player work in some exotic coordinates?

BTW, you can get rid off triginimetric functions with

```
dx = mouseX - player.x
dy = mouseY - player.y
len = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
dx = dx / len
dy = dy / len
pos.x +=  dx * his.speed
```

Comment: Depends on your definition of exotic. I keep a constant coordinate system where width and height are both 256 units. I use this so it will scale well on different screen sizes.

Comment: Im converting the player units to the mouse units, so I don't need to convert the mouse units.